# DirectionalViewPager with PageTransformer support

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/) to achieve vertical scrolling fragments in Android app.It works fine, but it's very simple. I want to apply PageTransformer to that to add animation, but it's not implemented there so it causes app crash when I invoke it. Has anyone ever tried to apply vertical scrolling in Android app? It seems that this is a huge problem to implement it. I also wonder why Android SDK only supports horizontal direction in ViewPager when it's quite common UI design pattern? Does anyone found solution for that? Or maybe knows how to approach the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently copy pasted the original v19 support `viewpager` and modified it a little bit to make it vertical. The lib is available on [Github](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager) and is pushed on MavenCentral.

The PageTransformer works, but the viewpager is only vertical.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thank you very much! Can you also provide me with some tips how to integrate it with my project (I'm working with Gradle in Android Studio)?. Adding just compile 'com.github.castorflex.verticalviewpager:library:19.0.0' to dependencies section doesn't help. I'm newbie in Android Development so it would be very helpful. Again: you're a man!

Comment: @jimmyweb Copy paste your build.gradle

Comment: now I've added your jar file from Maven Central "library-19.0.0-sources.jar", but still nada. 
Here's my gradle file: http://pastebin.com/eHcaunTF

Comment: @jimmyweb Try this http://pastebin.com/WgjKJXnJ and click on Sync project with Gradle Files